# Replace wildcard string inside double quote

Tags: javascript, string, replace, wildcard

I have this string

```
var newtypegraph=newtypegraph.replace(' "type":"bar3d" ',' "type":"area" ');
```

I want to make bar3d as wildcard.

Comment: Is this a JSON string?

Comment: Your question is very vague...what do you mean by *make as wildcard*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like JavaScript, so you can use regex:

```
var newtypegraph = newtypegraph.replace(/"type":".*?"/g, '"type":"area"');
```

This looks like the properties of a JSON object. Is this JSON?

Comment: Yes, they are. Confusing in using regex. Thanks for your quick help. Solved.

Comment: @SyamAhmad: Can you parse the JSON and just replace the properties with JavaScript?